# Korrekte Anrede bei Antwort mit allgemeiner E-Mail-Adresse

Tags: salutation, letter

Ich muss auf eine E-Mail antworten, die von einer Frau Meier geschrieben wurde, aber als Absender nur eine allgemeine E-Mail-Adresse (wie `kontakt@example.com`) hat.

Wie ist hier dir korrekte Anrede?

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,

oder

> Sehr geehrte Frau Meier,

oder eine Kombination?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the german language. It could be asked for most languages in the same way.

Comment: Ich stimme dafür, die Frage offenzulassen, denn in jeder Sprache gibt es verschiedene Konventionen. Der Kern dieser Frage ist »Wie handhabt das das Deutsche?« und mithin voll und ganz on-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das Problem ist nicht auf E-Mails beschränkt; die Papierpost, die ich von meinem zuständigen Jobcenter bekomme, hat auch stets eine Person, die unterzeichnet hat (Frau Müller*), während die Rücksendung ganz allgemein an die Abteilung geht und gegebenenfalls von jemand ganz anderem bearbeitet wird.

Dennoch denke ich, dass man das Antwortschreiben mit einer Anrede an Frau Müller – in deinem Fall, Frau Meier – beginnen sollte. Sie mag zwar nicht diejenige sein, welche die E-Mail zuerst zu Gesicht bekommt, aber sollte sie es doch sein, wäre »sehr geehrte Damen und Herren« unangebracht. Und wer weiß: Vielleicht landet ja die Post an `kontakt@unternehmen.de` in einem Postfach, das von einem Bot gescannt wird, der bei gewissen Schlüsselwörtern direkt an die zuständige Person weiterleitet?

Man kann außerdem weiterdenken. Üblicherweise wird in einer Antwort in irgendeiner Form auf das bisher gesagte zurückreferenziert. Zum Beispiel:

> Ihr Angebot vom 35.5. habe ich erhalten und möchte gerne die Tour zum Äquator mit einem Rollschuhe fahrenden Pferd buchen.

Gerade hier bezieht sich das *Ihr* auf Frau Meier, die ja das Angebot (elektronisch) unterzeichnet hat. Gegebenenfalls möchte hier der Eine oder Andere diskutieren, sollte im Ursprungsschreiben alles im Plural geschrieben worden sein. Ich halte das aber dennoch für wenig relevant, solange Frau Meier als Unterzeichnerin unten steht.

Fazit: Sobald man eine bestimmte Kontaktperson namentlich kennt, sollte man ihren Namen auch verwenden; auch wenn die E-Mail an eine allgemeine Adresse geht. Also:

> Sehr geehrte Frau Meier,

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese ausführliche Antwort!

Comment: @Stefan Bitte gerne. Ich persönlich hätte mit dem Annehmen zwar noch ein bisschen gewartet, ob noch andere Antworten kämen, aber ich will mich ja nicht beschweren ;)

Comment: Nicht eher "mit einem rollschuhfahrenden Pferd"?